# Flutter release build works but Testflight build crashes on swift_getObjectType

Tags: ios, flutter

I have built my flutter app with `flutter build ios — release` and it runs fine on my device (iPhone 13 Pro). But when I run a build from testflight it crashes.

I am not sure if the error is related to the `connectivity_plus` plugin because before I got the same error for the package `audioplayers`.

Source code: https://github.com/denniske/59seconds

Crash Report:

```
Incident Identifier: F4F11700-AD59-4AC2-8F4A-2247CC6D5D50
Beta Identifier:     05590F6C-9B4A-4F73-9F92-46C1485E6873
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,2
Process:             Runner [10720]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          app.fiftynineseconds.game
Version:             2.0.8 (20008)
AppStoreTools:       15A240a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone14,2:16
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           app.fiftynineseconds.game [3528]

Date/Time:           2023-09-18 10:05:26.5742 +0200
Launch Time:         2023-09-18 10:05:26.1338 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.6.1 (20G81)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.80.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4332666880
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   1023f4000-1023f8000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...er.app/Runner
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [10720]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x1b898e120 swift_getObjectType + 40
1   connectivity_plus                      0x1028d0668 static SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin.register(with:) + 116
2   connectivity_plus                      0x1028d0a0c @objc static SwiftConnectivityPlusPlugin.register(with:) + 56
3   connectivity_plus                      0x1028cda64 +[ConnectivityPlusPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 72
4   Runner                                 0x1023f94a4 +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 184
5   Runner                                 0x1023f9860 AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 104
6   Runner                                 0x1023f9ba4 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 196
7   UIKitCore                              0x1c0c2b054 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 300
8   UIKitCore                              0x1c0c2a78c -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 2848
9   UIKitCore                              0x1c0c29768 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 856
10  UIKitCore                              0x1c0c293b4 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 132
11  UIKitCore                              0x1c0971664 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112
12  UIKitCore                              0x1c0caf850 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216
13  UIKitCore                              0x1c0b61c5c -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 220
14  UIKitCore                              0x1c0b61a84 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 620
15  UIKitCore                              0x1c0b61634 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 252
16  UIKitCore                              0x1c0b61500 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148
17  UIKitCore                              0x1c124ea68 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736
18  UIKitCore                              0x1c12ed074 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224
19  UIKitCore                              0x1c0a0ec70 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316
20  UIKitCore                              0x1c0e801ac __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.223 + 556
21  UIKitCore                              0x1c0adfc60 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216
22  UIKitCore                              0x1c0adfad0 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244
23  UIKitCore                              0x1c0adf028 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 520
24  UIKitCore                              0x1c0adedb4 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288
25  FrontBoardServices                     0x1d48ec2e4 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 344
26  FrontBoardServices                     0x1d492c068 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.80 + 120
27  FrontBoardServices                     0x1d48f0120 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x1d492bcc0 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 360
29  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c5d37eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
30  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1c5d3b91c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
31  FrontBoardServices                     0x1d48fa24c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
32  FrontBoardServices                     0x1d48f9de8 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
33  FrontBoardServices                     0x1d48fc694 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
34  CoreFoundation                         0x1be93a128 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
35  CoreFoundation                         0x1be9467b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
36  CoreFoundation                         0x1be8cb648 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
37  CoreFoundation                         0x1be8e10d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
38  CoreFoundation                         0x1be8e63ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
39  GraphicsServices                       0x1f9dfc35c GSEventRunModal + 164
40  UIKitCore                              0x1c0c72f58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
41  UIKitCore                              0x1c0c72bbc UIApplicationMain + 340
42  Runner                                 0x1023f9d1c main + 64
43  dyld                                   0x1dde18dec start + 2220

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a1b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a1b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a1b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a1b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a1b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fd826ca4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fd839b74 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fd839e4c mach_msg_overwrite + 540
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1fd8271e8 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1be8e0024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1be8e1250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1be8e63ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
7   Foundation                             0x1b8b5afb4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8   Foundation                             0x1b8b5ae9c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64
9   UIKitCore                              0x1c0da5cc8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 416
10  Foundation                             0x1b8b74524 __NSThread__start__ + 716
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a26b8 _pthread_start + 148
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a1b88 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21e6a1b74 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x80000001028d6cd0   x2: 0xd000000000000026   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000005   x5: 0x000000002d400000   x6: 0x0000000280d749b0   x7: 0x000000010e773d90
    x8: 0x80000001028d6cd0   x9: 0x7fffffffffffffe0  x10: 0x00000000000009b0  x11: 0x00000000000007fb
   x12: 0x00000000ad7b2099  x13: 0x00000000000007fd  x14: 0x00000000ad9b289c  x15: 0x00000000ad7b2099
   x16: 0x00000001b898e0f8  x17: 0x000000002d800000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000215235330  x21: 0x0000000000000001  x22: 0x0000000000000001  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x000000021217a000  x26: 0x0000000212190000  x27: 0x000000002b870064
   x28: 0x0000000000000010   fp: 0x000000016da090a0   lr: 0xe023fa81028d0668
    sp: 0x000000016da09090   pc: 0x00000001b898e120 cpsr: 0x00001000
   far: 0x0000000000000000  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x1023f4000 -        0x102527fff Runner arm64  <c6414a2376083378b238904b06a96f37> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Runner
       0x1027d8000 -        0x1027effff FBLPromises arm64  <55fba274af4a3814ba363ba96cedad8b> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
       0x1027b0000 -        0x1027b7fff FirebaseAppCheckInterop arm64  <4723522fbdea36558031d1059cdd5827> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAppCheckInterop.framework/FirebaseAppCheckInterop
       0x102ac4000 -        0x102b3bfff FirebaseAuth arm64  <4273839129b13d58892860e7c4da9ec2> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FirebaseAuth.framework/FirebaseAuth
       0x102850000 -        0x102867fff FirebaseCore arm64  <e6608a8e49da3c128715dbc76df119fa> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore
       0x102920000 -        0x10294ffff FirebaseCoreInternal arm64  <87a046f21e563adb862e35d52cd6f414> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreInternal.framework/FirebaseCoreInternal
       0x1029b8000 -        0x1029d7fff FirebaseDynamicLinks arm64  <9492d5bf64c53ceca5dc71d66cc143ff> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FirebaseDynamicLinks.framework/FirebaseDynamicLinks
       0x104cf8000 -        0x105257fff FirebaseFirestore arm64  <ec38fceb80de3eb593069d94b236aff6> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestore.framework/FirebaseFirestore
       0x102c0c000 -        0x102c2bfff FirebaseInstallations arm64  <572cb398619c3545bcd6d39011de7f77> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations
       0x102d00000 -        0x102d4ffff GTMSessionFetcher arm64  <99dbe87044f13938a0ffea1ed4cd264a> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
       0x102c60000 -        0x102c87fff GoogleUtilities arm64  <946964a321c63beea8c526ce7b372418> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
       0x10288c000 -        0x10289ffff Reachability arm64  <1828a0d062fd35da8aa098a322bff5e4> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/Reachability.framework/Reachability
       0x1030bc000 -        0x1031abfff absl arm64  <c4d6366aa54933e490164af46938b840> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/absl.framework/absl
       0x1028c8000 -        0x1028d7fff connectivity_plus arm64  <37fe8200dae13cf49862f3d434be8f07> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/connectivity_plus.framework/connectivity_plus
       0x1028fc000 -        0x102907fff flutter_vibrate arm64  <c1a207f6bbcf3b5893e0b32b4160dca0> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_vibrate.framework/flutter_vibrate
       0x109bb4000 -        0x10a3fbfff grpc arm64  <9f04f49bfec53905b025806db08c93e6> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/grpc.framework/grpc
       0x103ea4000 -        0x104007fff grpcpp arm64  <8a995959368e374bbb70490377f0bb50> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/grpcpp.framework/grpcpp
       0x1027c4000 -        0x1027cbfff launch_review arm64  <bfb8b71b8b6b37e8a77840e101ff1e7e> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/launch_review.framework/launch_review
       0x1033dc000 -        0x10344ffff leveldb arm64  <448ab702cba83aa0b70e90d783b9c79c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/leveldb.framework/leveldb
       0x102830000 -        0x10283bfff nanopb arm64  <03036417e2a53187921e696cca97765c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
       0x103904000 -        0x103ad3fff openssl_grpc arm64  <e72d829106ed37fba1c7af5889b9a576> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/openssl_grpc.framework/openssl_grpc
       0x102814000 -        0x10281bfff package_info_plus arm64  <4d1b056576e335f2a53ffcc207bfaafd> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/package_info_plus.framework/package_info_plus
       0x102cbc000 -        0x102cc7fff path_provider_foundation arm64  <247bceff141d31f68b702770adb2d77f> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/path_provider_foundation.framework/path_provider_foundation
       0x102ce0000 -        0x102cebfff share_plus arm64  <1c654b4a3e5b33c3a2b468aab16b960c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/share_plus.framework/share_plus
       0x102da0000 -        0x102daffff shared_preferences_foundation arm64  <35f9451db4fc3be18ed51a255d23fbb9> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/shared_preferences_foundation.framework/shared_preferences_foundation
       0x102dc8000 -        0x102dd3fff url_launcher_ios arm64  <ba60342cf1003310ad5e84aae64dc8c0> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/url_launcher_ios.framework/url_launcher_ios
       0x102e7c000 -        0x102eb3fff webview_flutter_wkwebview arm64  <a04bc6c572833d11926f34bc4234c67d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/webview_flutter_wkwebview.framework/webview_flutter_wkwebview
       0x10c998000 -        0x10e6a3fff Flutter arm64  <4c4c444e55553144a1a24cea08ebacc4> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/06E4225B-8DBF-4D80-81E1-C48986C69699/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter
       0x102e64000 -        0x102e6ffff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <7e77fc541c3331c086e81fb7bf12836c> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x1b858c000 -        0x1b8ae4fff libswiftCore.dylib arm64e  <a4726d93179833868c5872e17d96a1a4> /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
       0x1c08d6000 -        0x1c20fafff UIKitCore arm64e  <7d57a1d1856f338d97db880c4ec8b02e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x1d48e9000 -        0x1d4990fff FrontBoardServices arm64e  <db727a51b28f330799d30bc671c3c46f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
       0x1c5d34000 -        0x1c5d7afff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <5d16936b4e4c3276ba7a69c9bc760aba> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
       0x1be867000 -        0x1bec4efff CoreFoundation arm64e  <a900b4590127379e9cba0eab9c5d559f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1f9dfb000 -        0x1f9e03fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <cd8d719514e13c7ca8c950ccea9f2a17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x1dde03000 -        0x1dde88a53 dyld arm64e  <c3fc2ee4367f3086beb8420ad442bf88> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x21e6a1000 -        0x21e6acff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <aa302f5affe5327aa0033b288b935de1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1fd826000 -        0x1fd85dfe7 libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <681b06a07f6b3fa3a2ce063dc1da7b1b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1b8b19000 -        0x1b93f6fff Foundation arm64e  <1715de5d08933af0b0c0550bb14f91ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was publishing a debug build to testflight. And opening a flutter app that has been built with debug mode from the home screen of a device leads to an error due to this open bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67624